# Сортировка по ключу Y

Tags: javascript, объекты, obj

подскажите как можно выполнить сортировку по возрастанию по y в данном массиве объектов:

```
var Objs = {
    0.98401984: {
        1: {
            x: 123,
            y: 123,
        },
        2: {
            x: 123,
            y: 123,
        },
        3: {
            x: 123,
            y: 123,
        },
    },
    0.12930572: {
        1: {
            x: 456,
            y: 456,
        },
        2: {
            x: 456,
            y: 456,
        },
        3: {
            x: 456,
            y: 456,
        },
     0.2309328: {
        1: {
            x: 789,
            y: 789,
        },
        2: {
            x: 789,
            y: 789,
        },
        3: {
            x: 789,
            y: 789,
        },
    },
```

в моем примере они уже отсортированы как мне нужно, но дело в том что когда объект меняет значение Y то данная сортировка нарушается, а мне нужно ее сохранять...

Comment: о сортировке какой вложенности идет речь? Там где ключи целые числа или дробные?. П.С:  да и вообще - сортировка объекта  дело не благодарное.

Comment: извините если не правильно описал свой вопрос, просто я новичок на данном портале, мне нужна сортировка по значению Y, если у объекта 0.283791989 (это рандомное значение из Math.random() ) Y больше других объектов 0.nnnn то его на первое место в массиве Objs и те у которых оно чуть меньше их помещать на 2,3 ... n места...
еще раз извените если опять не точно описал свою проблему !

Comment: `Objs` - не массив, а объект (в понимании JS). Объекты не принято сортировать, потому что стандартными методами они не сортируются https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in#v-kakom-poryadke-perebirayutsya-svoystva

Comment: и как же быть просто нужно реализовать ось Z то есть 3D модель ?
я буду рад любому ответу )

Comment: а какой смысл вообще Вам сортировать объект, если к его значениям вы всё равно обращаетесь по ключу, а не по индексу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это то что вам надо

```
var Objs = {
    0.98401984: {
        1: {
            x: 123,
            y: 5,
        },
        2: {
            x: 123,
            y: 1,
        },
        3: {
            x: 123,
            y: 12,
        },
    },
    0.12930572: {
        1: {
            x: 456,
            y: 4342356,
        },
        2: {
            x: 456,
            y: 4256,
        },
        3: {
            x: 456,
            y: 423456,
        },
    },
    0.2309328: {
        1: {
            x: 789,
            y: -789,
        },
        2: {
            x: 789,
            y: 2342789,
        },
        3: {
            x: 789,
            y: 23789,
        },
    },
}



for (const key in Objs) {
    var temp =[];
    for (const key2 in Objs[key]) {
        temp.push(Objs[key][key2]);
    }
    temp = temp.sort((a, b) => a.y - b.y);

    Objs[key] = {};

    for (let i= 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        Objs[key][i + 1] = temp[i];
    }
}



console.log(Objs);
```

Выведет

```
{ '0.98401984':
   { '1': { x: 123, y: 1 },
     '2': { x: 123, y: 5 },
     '3': { x: 123, y: 12 } },
  '0.12930572':
   { '1': { x: 456, y: 4256 },
     '2': { x: 456, y: 423456 },
     '3': { x: 456, y: 4342356 } },
  '0.2309328':
   { '1': { x: 789, y: -789 },
     '2': { x: 789, y: 23789 },
     '3': { x: 789, y: 2342789 } } }
```

вот тогда почитал ваш комент

```
var tempY = [];
for (const key in Objs) {

    for (const key2 in Objs[key]) {
        tempY.push({
            name: key,
            data: {
                y: Objs[key][key2].y,
                x: Objs[key][key2].x
            }
        })
    }
}


var highest = tempY.sort((a, b) => b.data.y - a.data.y)[0];


var result = {};
var names = Array.from(new Set(tempY.map(v => v.name)));

for (const value of names) {
    var local = {};

    var data = tempY.filter(v => v.name == value).map(v => v.data).sort((a, b ) => a.y - b.y);

    for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
        local[index + 1] = {
            x: data[index].x,
            y: data[index].y
        }
    }

    result[value] = local
}

console.log(result);
```

Выведет

```
{ '0.12930572':
   { '1': { x: 456, y: 4256 },
     '2': { x: 456, y: 423456 },
     '3': { x: 456, y: 4342356 } },
  '0.2309328':
   { '1': { x: 789, y: -789 },
     '2': { x: 789, y: 23789 },
     '3': { x: 789, y: 2342789 } },
  '0.98401984':
   { '1': { x: 123, y: 1 },
     '2': { x: 123, y: 5 },
     '3': { x: 123, y: 12 } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отсортировать объект, его нужно превратить в массив

```js
let Objs = [
   {
  1: {
      x: 123,
      y: 123,
  },
  2: {
      x: 123,
      y: 123,
  },
  3: {
      x: 123,
      y: 123,
  },
  },
   {
  1: {
      x: 456,
      y: 456,
  },
  2: {
      x: 456,
      y: 456,
  },
  3: {
      x: 456,
      y: 456,
  },
},
{
  1: {
      x: 789,
      y: 789,
  },
  2: {
      x: 789,
      y: 789,
  },
  3: {
      x: 789,
      y: 789,
  },
  },
];

Objs[2][1].y = 100

Objs = Objs.sort((a,b) => {
   return a[1].y-b[1].y
});
console.log(Objs)
```

Какой вопрос - такой ответ((

Comment: если превратить его из объекта в массив то я не смогу использовать функции отрисовки которые принимают только объект (((

Comment: Перед передачей в функцию отрисовку переформатируйте массив, обратно, в объект. Хотя странный метод, который не может перебрать массив, как объект. Если бы было наоборот, я бы еще понял...

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! я попробую сделать то что вы посоветовали мне )

Answer (score 0):

Объект сортировать геморройно и бессмысленно. 
Если вам нужно ВЫВОДИТЬ куда-то объект, сохраняя определенный порядок свойств, то создайте массив, в который выведите эти свойства в нужном порядке:

```
var ObjIndexer = ["0.98401984", "0.12930572", "0.2309328", ...]
```

Если потом вам требуется дергать функцию, которая принимает только объекты, передавая ей их в нужном порядке, передавайте их, например, в цикле, перебирающем вышеуказанный массив:

```
for (i = 0; i < ObjIndexer.length; i++) {
    your_function(Objs[ObjIndexer[i]]);
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем кто принял участие в этом моем вопросе, вы очень помогли мне !

Comment: Тогда примите правильный ответ и лайкните, если понравилось =)